# Why aren't Adsense banners placed in the center?

Tags: adsense

Why aren't Adsense banners placed in the center? It feels weird, I don't think Google messed up the simple problem => It may be my fault.

```js
   <ins
      className={`adsbygoogle ${className}`}
      style={style}
      data-ad-client={client}
      data-ad-slot={slot}
      // data-ad-layout={layout}
      // data-ad-layout-key={layoutKey}
      data-ad-format={format} //  "horizontal"
      data-full-width-responsive={fullWidthResponsive} // true
      {...rest}
    >
    </ins>
```

[image]